# Why there is a difference between the ARGB component I'm saving and the one I'm retrieving from the saved file?

Tags: c#, bitmap, save, argb

[Offtopic] Please excuse me if I'm not accurate enough, this is my first question and I'm also new to programming.

[Question] I wanted to change the ARGB component of a single pixel of a bitmap (photo, jpg file) to an exact value using Bitmap.SetPixel and saving it to a new file, using Bitmap.Save. Unfortunately it didn't work. When I re-opened the file, the pixel I wanted to change (0, 0) had slightly different ARGB values. Why this is happening? Is it possible to create a file that has exactly the ARGB component that I want for a certain pixel?

Here is the code I have:

```
Bitmap originalMap = new Bitmap("image.jpg");

Color current = originalMap.GetPixel(0, 0);
//This one shows the original ARGB values
Console.WriteLine(current);

originalMap.SetPixel(0, 0, Color.FromArgb(255, 100, 100, 100));
originalMap.Save("new.jpg");
//This one shows the result that I want, but the bitmap is not re-opened
Console.WriteLine(originalMap.GetPixel(0, 0));

Bitmap openTheNewFile = new Bitmap("new.jpg");
//The actual result after I open the saved file, A=255, R=108, G=113, B=117
Console.WriteLine(openTheNewFile.GetPixel(0, 0));
```

Why it's 108, 113 and 117 and not 100, 100, 100?

Thanks in advance for the answers, I'm pretty sure that this is something basic (to say the least), but it really bothers me.

Comment: _jpg .. exact value_  these are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Thanks TaW! I will keep this in mind the next time I try to make such changes to an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPEG uses a lossy compression algorithm. If you set a single pixel in the original image the corresponding pixel in the compressed image will most likely not have the exact same color values anymore.

To preserve exact color values, use a lossless compression format such as PNG, or use uncompressed bitmaps.

Comment: Thank you so much! Great answer! I thought I will have to wait maybe a day or so. Thanks again! All the best!